# Changing the "group by" in an NSFetchedResultsController

Tags: ios, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller, magicalrecord

I'm using an `NSFetchedResultsController`, and I need to be able to change the grouping of my data. I'm also integrating `MagicalRecord`.

Here's where I create my `self.fetchedResultsController`:

```
_fetchedResultsController = [WREntry MR_fetchAllGroupedBy:self.sortDescriptor.key withPredicate:[self tagsPredicate] sortedBy:self.sortDescriptor.key ascending:NO delegate:self inContext:[NSManagedObjectContext MR_defaultContext]];
```

When my sort descriptor is changed, I am able to update the `sortBy`. See below:

```
self.fetchedResultsController.fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = @[self.sortDescriptor, [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"name" ascending:YES]];
```

I can't figure out how to update the grouping of the data, and as a result, I'm not seeing any data. The `fetchedResultsController` is still grouping by the previous value.

Anyone know how to resolve this?

Note: I've tried using this:

```
NSDictionary *entityProperties = [[WREntry MR_entityDescription] propertiesByName];
NSPropertyDescription *groupBy = [entityProperties valueForKeyPath:self.sortDescriptor.key];

self.fetchedResultsController.fetchRequest.propertiesToGroupBy = @[groupBy];
```

but for some reason, `groupBy` is nil, even though `entityProperties` and `self.sortDescriptor.key` are not nil.

Answer (score 0):

Likely you're going to either

1. Call performFetch: on the NSFetchedResultsController again
2. Create a new instance of your NSFRC with the new request and,again, call performFetch: again